# ¿Cómo pasar un valor de una variable de javascript a php?

Tags: javascript

Estoy generando unos div dinámicamente con `jquery` y con  el método `eq` le asigno valores(índices) a cada div, porque necesito extraer un valor que traen desde la base de datos y ese valor lo necesito para hacer una actualización a la `bd` por medio de `php` lo intento con `Ajax`, con `FETCH`  y no me funciona no se como pasar ese valor  que capturo en `js` a php.

En `php` lo estoy trabajando con `mvc`.

eso lo que tengo en js

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.co').on('click',function(){

       var x= $('.co').index(this);
        var w=$('.codocu').eq(x);
        var r=$(w).val();

      fetch('index.php', {
       method: 'POST',
       body: body

})

.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);


});


});
```

Comment: Puedes usar ajax o meterlo todo dentro de un formulario y enviarlo. Dime que prefieres y te hago una muestra. Con ajax no se recarga la web, con el formulario se recarga pero queda en el mismo sitio, si cambiar de página. Si muestras el php que tienes y el html podremos afinar un poco mas.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu ayuda creo, que prefiero usar ajax por que no recarga la pagina

Answer (score 2):

Lo que estas intentando es correcto, [ajax](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) es lo que te hace falta para que javascript interactúe con php, el problema está en esa llamada, que no funciona como esperas.

Por lo que veo el [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) no es jquery y además como indica la documentación:

> **Esta es una tecnología experimental**
>
> Comprueba la Tabla de compabilidad
>   de navegadores cuidadosamente antes de usarla en producción.

Yo te sugiero que uses [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.co').on('click', function () {

        var x = $('.co').index(this);
        var w = $('.codocu').eq(x);
        var r = $(w).val();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'procesar_valores.php', 
            data: {valor_x: x, valor_w: w, valor_r: r}
        }).success(function (data) {
               console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

En la llamada he puesto un script inventado (procesar_valores.php), debes poner el valor que corresponda, así como los nombres de los campos que deseas enviar.

Answer (score -1):

Lo más rentable que conozco sería algo como:

```
$tuvariablephp = echo '<script>var valorDetuVariableScript;</script>'
```

Espero me entiendas y te funcione algo similar, saludos.

Comment: Esta línea no tiene sentido, `php` se procesa en el lado del servidor y es el que genera el html que da soporte al javascript que ejecutará el navegador en el lado del cliente.  No puedes mezclar estos dos ámbitos de esta manera tan lineal.